# Removing background color in holoviews image

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

What is the correct way to specify the background colour for a Holoviews image? Here's the example I am using:

```py
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
hv.extension('bokeh')
eye = np.eye(10)
hv.Image(eye).opts(clipping_colors={0: 'red'})
```

I also tried defining `clipping_colors` with other values like `NaN` or `"0"`, but they all give a faint blue background color as in the attached image. [image: holoviews background color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background color is specified like `.opts(bgcolor=<color>)`, but note that the background will only show for missing pixels, and `eye` here is a dense array, with no NaN values. If you want zero to be treated like missing value, then you can specify that:

```py
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
hv.extension('bokeh')
eye = np.eye(10)
hv.Image(eye).opts(bgcolor="red").redim.nodata(z=0)
```

[image: eye matrix with red bg]